# How to copy 2 sheets to one in order to create pdf?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets with specific layouts. If I use method `sourceSheet1.UsedRange.Copy destinationSheet.Cells(1, 1)` with each sheet then I loose the layout in the end. The same happens with `PasteSpecial Paste:=`. I don't loose the layout only if I copy the sheet entirely

```
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test")
ws1.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
```

But don't know how to copy two sheets into one

Comment: What do you expect? If you copy the entire sheet2 into sheet1, at least some of the layout (Column width, header and footer...) will be either from sheet1 or from sheet2.

Comment: They have the same width of the columns